# How to initialize a dropdown with pre-selected values?

Tags: angular, typescript

So i am using Angular 8(for the first time, so sorry if this is noob question) to create a UI for a .Net Core backend, and I have this object

```
    {
    "tipoId": 1,
    "name": "Jato D'Agua",
    "operations": [
        {
            "operationId": 3,
            "name": "Desapertar",
            "descricao": "Serve para desapertar parafusos",
            "duracao": 5
        },
        {
            "operationId": 5,
            "name": "Apertar",
            "descricao": "Serve para apertar parafusos",
            "duracao": 5
        }
    ]
    }
```

And my Type of Machine is declared like this :

```
export class TypeMachine {
  tipoId?: number;
  name: string;
  listOperation: Operation[];
}
```

Because the user can modify the list of operation I am using a Multiple Select([Here](https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview)), I can already show all the operations available, but i dont know how to pre-select with the ones that are in the object TypeMachine.

My Html:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Operacoes</mat-label>
    <mat-select [formControl]="formArray" multiple>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let operacao of (operacoes$ | async)" [value]="operacao.id">
                                {{operacao.name}}</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

And my component.ts is looking like this

```
export class TipomaquinaAddEditComponent implements OnInit {
  operacoes$: Observable<Operation[]>;

  form: FormGroup;
  actionType: string;
  formName: string;
  formArray: Operation[];
  tipoId: number;
  errorMessage: any;
  existingTipo: TipoMaquina;

  constructor(
    private tipomaquinaService: TipomaquinaService,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private avRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    private operacaoService: OperacaoService
  ) {
    const idParam = 'id';
    this.actionType = 'Add';
    this.formName = 'name';
    this.formArrayIds = number [];

    if (this.avRoute.snapshot.params[idParam]) {
      this.tipoId = this.avRoute.snapshot.params[idParam];
    }
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    if (this.tipoId > 0) {
      this.actionType = 'Edit';
      this.loadOperacoes();
      this.tipomaquinaService.getTipoMaquina(this.tipoId)
        .subscribe(
          data => (
            (this.existingTipo = data),
            this.form.controls[this.formName].setValue(data.name)
          )
        );
    }
  }

  save() {
    if (!this.form.valid) {
      return;
    }

    // if (this.actionType === 'Add') {
    //   const tipo: TipoMaquina = {
    //     name: this.form.get(this.formName).value,
    //     listOperacaoId: Array[]
    //   };

    //   this.tipomaquinaService.saveTipoMaquina(tipo).subscribe(data => {
    //     this.router.navigate(['/tipomaquina', data.tipoId]);
    //     this.router.navigate(['/tiposmaquina']);
    //   });
    // }

    if (this.actionType === 'Edit') {
      const tipo: TipoMaquina = {
        tipoId: this.existingTipo.tipoId,
        name: this.form.get(this.formName).value,
        listOperacao: this.form.get('operacoes').value
      };
      this.tipomaquinaService
        .updateTipoMaquina(tipo.tipoId, tipo)
        .subscribe(data => {
          this.router.navigate([this.router.url]);

          this.router.navigate(['/tiposmaquina']);
        });
    }
  }

  cancel() {
    this.router.navigate(['/tiposmaquina']);
  }

  get name() {
    return this.form.get(this.formName);
  }

  get operacoes() {
    return this.form.get('operacoes') as FormArray;
  }

  loadOperacoes() {
    this.operacoes$ = this.operacaoService.getOperacoes();
  }

}
```

So doing a summary what i need to achieve is:

- Pre Select the entries of the multi selector
- Retrieve the selected entries when user save the changes.

I can i do that?

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0):

```
<mat-form-field>
   <mat-label>Select an option</mat-label>
   <mat-select [(value)]="selected">
   <mat-option>None</mat-option>
   <mat-option value="option1">Option 1</mat-option>
   <mat-option value="option2">Option 2</mat-option>
   <mat-option value="option3">Option 3</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

The mat-select control has an input property named value. Create a property named selected. If you are using formcontrols you need to bind the selected field in the formcontrol definition. Then you can use the formcontrol's setValue to set it from code.

Comment: That selected field you talk, can be an array?

Comment: Yes arrays are allowed make sure multiselect is true